# How to reference Microsoft.Office.Core (office.dll) in .Net Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

How to reference `Microsoft.Office.Core (office.dll)`

> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\office.dll)

in .Net Core (full framework)?

Comment: I'm looking for the same dll to incorporate in .net winforms

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit of a [known pain point](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/184) in the current tooling. For now, you need to pack the DLL into a nuget package, add the location of that package to your nuget sources and install it that way. It's a bit of work for a DLL you don't maintain, but it seems to be working.

Comment: That's because Microsoft.Office.Core not have a NuGet package?

Comment: Correct. There are some unofficial packages, but without knowing anything about them I'd just make my own.